# To test whether a list match with another list in R

Tags: r, list

"a" and "b" are lists.

```
a<-list(matrix(c(0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,1),4), matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,1,0),3), matrix(c(0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,1,0,1,2,0),5))
b<-list(matrix(c(2,2,1,1),1),matrix(c(1,2,1,2),1),matrix(c(2,1,2,1),1))

>a
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    2    2    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    2
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    2    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2    1
[4,]    0    0    0    2
[5,]    2    0    2    0

> b
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    1    2

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    2    1
```

There both are three objects in list "a" and "b".

My aim is to test whether the **non-zero** elements in each row in the list "a" match with the corresponding position of corresponding object in list "b".

For example, the first object in "a" is:

```
 [[1]]
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    0    0    1    0
    [2,]    2    2    0    0
    [3,]    0    0    0    2
    [4,]    0    0    0    1
```

the first object in "b" is:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    1    1
```

We can see the non-zero number in Row 1 of list "a" is 1, it locates at the third place of the row, and the third place of the first object in "b" is also 3, so we call it matched! The result should come out with a "TRUE".
The non-zero number in Row 2 of list "a" is 2  2  , they locate in the first and second place of the row, and the first and second place of the first object in "b" are also 2  2, so we call it matched! The result should also come out with a "TRUE". ...and so forth.

So the expected result should be:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] 
[1,]  TRUE   
[2,]  TRUE   
[3,] FALSE  
[4,]  TRUE

[[2]]
     [,1] 
[1,]  TRUE  
[2,] FALSE  
[3,]  TRUE   

[[3]]
     [,1] 
[1,]  TRUE   
[2,]  TRUE  
[3,]  TRUE   
[4,] FALSE  
[5,]  TRUE
```

Comment: @RichardScriven I can only work out in one object to one object, but with a list, I don't know how to handle it together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea.  This checks each `b` vector against each row of the corresponding matrix in `a`, each with the zeros.  A match is TRUE, and FALSE otherwise.

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    matrix(apply(x, 1, function(z) identical(y[z != 0], z[z != 0])))
}

Map(f, a, b)
# [[1]]
#       [,1]
# [1,]  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE
#
# [[2]]
#       [,1]
# [1,]  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE
#
# [[3]]
#       [,1]
# [1,]  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE
# [5,]  TRUE
```

Comment: My attempt code is more complicated than yours. I try to find out which one in "a" is >0 and then match them the corresponding place in list "b", your code is so simplified, really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Richard. Could you help me with an advanced problem, if the one object of list "b" containes two rows, such as b<-list(matrix(c(2,2,1,1),1),matrix(c(1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1),2),matrix(c(2,1,2,1),1))‌​. I want to print out two columns of result in object 2, I really don't know how to handle it, thank you!  @Richard Scriven

Comment: I work it out by myself, I add an "apply" before your code: `Map(function(x, y) {
    apply(y,1,function(c) {matrix(apply(x, 1, function(z) identical(c[z != 0], z[z != 0])))})},a,b)`. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.  I was just waking up and reading these.

Comment: It doesn't matter! Big Thanks! @Richard Scriven

Answer (score 2):

```
mapply(function(x, y) rowSums(!(t(t(x) == c(y)) | x == 0)) == 0, a, b)
# [[1]]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#
# [[3]]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```